# how to close File Stream in C#

Tags: c#, filestream

Please see this code.

```
string name = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
byte[] documentBytes = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["DocumentContent"];

int readBytes = 0;
//int index = 0;
readBytes = documentBytes.Length;
try
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
    {

        fs.Write(documentBytes, 0, readBytes);
        //System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        //prc.StartInfo.FileName = fs.Name;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        app.Visible = false;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(fs.Name);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1]; // Explicit cast is not required here
     //   lastRow = worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row; 

        app.Visible = true;


        fs.Flush();
        fs.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have clicked more than one time. File is already open.", "WorkFlow", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

I am opening an excel file using the file stream. Excel is showing up nicely. But I am not able to close file stream. It still comes with a small pop up that shows 'File Now available'. How to get rid of that? I can see fs.Close() and Flush() really not working here. Please help.

Comment: "File now available"? is that really the message?

Comment: Excel just notices that you used FileShare.Read on the file, so knows it can't be written to and has to open the file in readonly mode.  Once you close the file it gets happy again.  So the workaround is simple, close the file *before* you start Excel.

Comment: Your code has both `using` and `Close` for the stream - It's redundant to have both.

Comment: "File now available"? is that really the message? –  Yes. I am getting the excel file as I wanted and then this popup.

Comment: That's the message coming from Excel. You'd need to suppress it from within Excel.

Comment: if i put a breakpoint just after app.visble = true, I am getting the Excel as I wanted and Not getting the small pop up. Pop message comes only after the using statements are over

Comment: @HansPassant... your Tip was super. It worked !!!! That was the mistake from my side. And it really make a  sense. Thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

You're asking Excel to open the file while you still have the stream open. Given that you're just trying to write bytes to it, I'd just use:

```
// This will close the file handle after writing the data
File.WriteAllBytes(name, documentBytes);

// Then you're fine to get Excel to open it
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
app.Visible = false;
var workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(name);
```

Comment: name is not working in var workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(name);

Comment: @SajithSudhi: "Is not working" gives us basically no information, making it very hard to help you

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in WorkFlowUAT.exe

Additional information: Sorry, we couldn't find letter.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

Comment: @SajithSudhi: Well Hans effectively gave the same answer as I did, at roughly the same time. I can't see why the file wouldn't be found by Excel if you genuinely used my code that created the file immediately before opening Excel...